# Editing activity theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm trying to edit theme like this:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

But this colours my whole activity. Instead I want only action bar to be coloured with my custom color. How to achieve this?

Edit:
I've managed to achieve desired result by using Theme Editor and creating custom theme with it.

Comment: how did you apply ur style ?

Comment: In AndroidManifest.xml  `<activity android:name=".myactivity2" android:label="My Activity2" android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"></activity>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

and please read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) for more info

Comment: this works, but I get this warning: `android:colorPrimary requires API level 21 (current min is 15)`

Comment: Please don't use android: colorPrimary, use only colorPrimary namespace.

Comment: but when I use it without `android: ` it doesn't change my ActionBar color

Comment: Did you change your parent theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar ?

Comment: Yes. And everything works fine if i use `android: ` but with that warning I mentioned earlier. Whenever I delete `android: ` colours go back to default.

Comment: what about changing theme from `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` on other activities?

Comment: Do you have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` in your  build.gradle bcz in order to use AppCompat Theme, you have to add this dependency.

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I've fixed this problem by using Theme editor. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompat theme. Specify `colorPrimary`atribute since the ActionBar background color depends on it.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try it like this ,
 Use a parent style and declare your whatever `Widget` style inside the parent one.Here use `android:actionBarStyle`

See the example below

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

set `MyTheme` in your activity

Note : `ActionBar` will not work for your target environment which is at API level 10